# ww.w3.org/1999/xhtml]. JAR containing the TLD may not be in the classpath

Tags: jsf, icefaces

when i am trying to running jsf project using the ice faces  i am getting  this error   10:56:54,144 ERROR JspPageToDocument:104 - Can't find TLD for location www.w3.org/1999/xhtml]. JAR containing the TLD may not be in the classpath . waht needs to be add to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of IceFaces 1.x  problems with JSPX.
Either upgrade IceFaces to latest available 1.x version, or use Facelets (XHTML) instead of JSPX, or use "plain" JSP instead of JSPX (i.e. get rid of `<jsp:xxx>` tags).